# How to get date from this string? just date

Tags: php, string, date

`$string = NCPDP_2016-10-28_15-31-10.csv;`

How to get date without extension and "_", just "2016-10-28 15-31-10"?

Answer (score 1):

Well this is shorter way. You can add variables $setup and $explode add to function if you wish to use them again.

```
$string = 'NCPDP_2016-10-28_15-31-10.csv';

$setup = str_replace("_", ".csv", $string);
$explode = explode(".csv", $setup);

echo $explode[1].' '.$explode[2];
```

Result will be

```
2016-10-28 15-31-10
```

Answer (score 1):

Here's an even shorter version:

```
$string = 'NCPDP_2016-10-28_15-31-10.csv';
echo trim(preg_replace('/([^\d\-])/', ' ', $string));
```

We simply replace everything that isn't a number or a dash with a space. The reason we do that instead of just remove them totally is to keep the space between the date and the time.

Now we can trim all white spaces away but keep the one in the middle (between the date and time).

Answer (score 0):

More than likely a better way of doing it but this will work.

```
$string  = "NCPDP_2016-10-28_15-31-10.csv";
$explode = explode( '_', $string );
echo $explode[ 1 ]."\n";
$explode2 = explode( '.', $explode[ 2 ] );
echo $explode2[ 0 ];
```

Result:

```
2016-10-28
15-31-10
```

Answer (score 0):

Simplest way to do it.

```
    $str1 = 'NCPDP_2016-10-28_15-31-10.csv'; 
    $replacestr = str_replace("_", ".csv", $str1);
    $explode = explode(".csv", $replacestr);   
    echo $explode[1].' '.$explode[2];
```